# Model binding with a child object

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have a class:

```
public class Application
{
      ....
      public Deployment NewDeployment { get; set; }
      ....
}
```

I have an editor template for Deployment within the Application View folder.

The ApplicationViewModel has a SelectedApplication (of type Application), in my Index.cshtml where I use ApplicationViewModel as my Model, I have this call:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Deployment", new { @id = Model.SelectedId, 
  q = Model.Query }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", role = "form" }))
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SelectedApplication.NewDeployment)
}
```

Which then correctly renders out the control in my DisplayTemplates\Deployment.cshtml (though, it may just be pulling the display code and nothing in relation to the NewDeployment object's contents). All is well in the world until I go to submit. At this stage everything seems good. Controller looks like:

```
public class DeploymentController : Controller
{
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Create(Deployment NewDeployment)
  {
    Deployment.CreateDeployment(NewDeployment);
    return Redirect("/Application" + Request.Url.Query);
  }
}
```

However, when it goes to DeploymentController -> Create, the object has nulls for values. If I move the NewDeployment object to ApplicationViewModel, it works fine with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewDeployment)
```

I looked at the output name/id which was basically SelectedApplication_NewDeployment, but unfortunately changing the Create signature to similar didn't improve the results. Is it possible to model bind to a child object and if so, how?

Comment: If you only want to post back a child model, you can use `public ActionResult Create(Bind(Prefix="SelectedApplication")]Deployment NewDeployment)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Stephen Muecke's comment and with slight modifications, I was able to find how to correct it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create ([Bind(Prefix="SelectedApplication.NewDeployment")] Deployment deployment)
{
  // do things
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your POST action should accept the same model your form is working with, i.e.:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ApplicationViewModel model)
```

Then, you'll be able to get at the deployment the same way as you did in the view:

```
model.SelectedApplication.NewDeployment
```

It was technically an accident that using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewDeployment)` worked. The only reason it did is because the action accepted a parameter named `NewDeployment`. If the parameter had been named anything else, like just `deployment`. It would have also failed.

Comment: My form encapsulates only the NewDeployment component. There are actually quite a few forms around this area (right before the deployment rendering code is ApplicationController.Create code that renders the same thing for Applications, as they're both modals they're pretty close by. Is it possible to work within that or no?